# Continuation of 'app not working in Droid' investigation: the code. Can anyone see any obvious error here?

Tags: android, surfaceview, motorola

In my previous question I asked if `System.currentTimeMillis()` was buggy in Droid, and the answer was no.

I assume the problem I'm having is somewhere else. While I wait for my Droid lone-user to report if a test app works on his phone, I would like to post some relevant code here.

*Please keep in mind that I removed everything in the code I thought would be irrelevant (posting the code leading to the first suspicious line in the log). I might have removed the code where the problem is, but I doubt it. It smells like a layout, not code,  problem. I say this because (see last line, where the log is) the surface is 0.*

Best regards, Ari.

**MANIFEST**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".BeMeBB" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="BeMeBBPref" android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="5" />
<supports-screens>
</supports-screens>
```

**LAYOUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="0pt" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom" android:background="#00000001">

    <android.view.SurfaceView android:id="@+id/preview_LAND"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:keepScreenOn="true" android:layout_margin="0pt">
    </android.view.SurfaceView>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/ACCELERATION_LINE" android:text="0  2  4  6  8  10 12 14 16 18 20  "
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:typeface="monospace" android:layout_weight="0"
            android:textSize="20dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp" android:background="#66000000" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/ACCELERATION" android:text="@string/Accelerometers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:typeface="monospace" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="0" android:textSize="20dp" android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:background="#66000000" />

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom" android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button android:id="@+id/SAVE_LAND" android:text="@string/Save"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="left|bottom"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0"
                android:textSize="26dp" android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:padding="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**CODE**

```
public class BeMeBB extends Activity implements OnClickListener, android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener, SensorEventListener {
    private SurfaceView preview=null;
    private SurfaceHolder previewHolder=null;

    SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            DoRecording();      
        }   
    }; // End SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_land);
        preview=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.preview_LAND);
        previewHolder=preview.getHolder();
        previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
        previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    } // End OnCreate

    private void DoRecording() {
        m_worker.setSurfaceHolder(previewHolder);
    } // End DoRecording
} // End class
```

**IN ANOTHER CLASS**

```
public void setSurfaceHolder(SurfaceHolder previewHolder) { 
    m_previewHolder = previewHolder;
    m_surface = m_previewHolder.getSurface();   
    Log.d("BeMeBB", "BeMeBBWorker m_surface="  + m_surface);
} //End  setSurfaceHolder
```

**AND THE RESULT IN LOG (SURFACE IS NOT VALID):**

```
11-19 17:58:13.171 D/BeMeBB  ( 1404): BeMeBBService m_surface=Surface(native-token=0)
```

Comment: Was your problem not related to the getting of the current time? I don't see anything related to that here.

Comment: From the documentation for getSurface(): "A rule of thumb is that application code should never have to call this method."

Comment: fixedd, indeed you are correct. I am following commonsware previous advice and finding what else could be causing the trouble, since he said that the time methods work fine in Droid.  I am investigating my preview surfaces now. Regards, Ari

Comment: commonsware: I see what you mean, they mention not to use getSurface. That's weird...  I use a surface for MediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay (Surface sv). Maybe I'll change to Camera.setPreviewDisplay(SurfaceHolder).

Comment: DEAD END: Cannot have a previewed media recorder that works on 1.5 and 2.0.

1. MediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay (Surface sv) REQUIRES use of getSurface.

2. Camera.setPreviewDisplay(SurfaceHolder sh) REQUIRES use of MediaRecorder.setCamera for preview, but setCamera is apparently broken "Known limitation - locked camera" in API 3.

So my only option is, (assuming  MediaRecorder.setCamera  is not broken in Android2.0 - they added an unlock) is to have two separate versions , one for API 3 and one for API 5. This is pretty bad!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it's confirmed, my lone Droid user sent back the 2 log files from:

1. A test app using MediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay (Surface sv). It REQUIRES use of getSurface, which crashes in API 5 on Droid phone.
2. A test app using Camera.setPreviewDisplay(SurfaceHolder sh). It REQUIRES use of MediaRecorder.setCamera for preview, but setCamera is apparently broken "Known limitation - locked camera" in API 3.

So: I Cannot have a previewed media recorder that works on 1.5 and 2.0. So my only option is, (confirmed MediaRecorder.setCamera is not broken in Android2.0 - they added an unlock) is to have two separate versions , one for API 3 and one for API 5.

Thank you commonsware for pointing me in the right direction. I will change the status to "answered" once I try again with deviceanywhere, just to be safe.